# Send anonymous emails C#

Tags: c#, email, send, anonymous

Hi I want to send password validation to my users using c#, and I wish to protect my mail box getting spammed. How do I do that?

Been trying to this and it's not working:

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

smtpClient.Timeout = 10000;
smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login", "password");

MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();
mailMsg.From = new MailAddress("noreply@mysite.com");
mailMsg.To.Add("user");
mailMsg.CC.Add("cc@ccServer.com");
mailMsg.Bcc.Add("bcc@bccServer.com");
mailMsg.Subject = "Subject";
mailMsg.Body = "BodyOfTheMailString";
smtpClient.Send(mailMsg); 
Console.WriteLine("Mail sent");
```

The user i am sending this email to, getting my gmail account as the sender

Comment: You can select whatever sender email you want

Comment: You don't need anonymous emails just to avoid getting spammed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not C#'s task, neither the body of your message: its your mailbox configuration.

If this is just for email validation, you can always create a new email like "service@domain.com" or "noreply@domain.com" for sending these verifications messages and then set this mailbox to ignore incoming messages.

Also if you try to send messages using emails that are not registered into your server, the server can deny your request.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE:

You should initially have mentioned that you are using gmail's smtp. To prevent people to send spam gmail always sets from to your emailaddress regardless of what you write in the From property.

Set the From address on the MailMessage to "noreply@mysite.com".

```
MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();
mailMsg .From = "noreply@mysite.com";
mailMsg .To = "to@toServer.com";
mailMsg .Cc = "cc@ccServer.com"";
mailMsg .Bcc = "bcc@bccServer.com";
mailMsg .Subject = "Subject";
mailMsg .Body = "BodyOfTheMailString";
SmtpMail.Send(mailMsg );
```

Comment: If this doesn't work, the answer may be to configure your SMTP server to properly behave for the user `noreply`. Depends on your setup.

Comment: it set's my gmail account as the account the mail been sent from

Comment: Yes I know. As I wrote in my updated answer you won't be able to change from address if you're using gmail's smtp.

Comment: `MailAddress ma = new MailAddress("noreply@mysite.com");
            MailAddressCollection mac = new MailAddressCollection();
            mac.Add("noreply@mysite.com");`  works