# How to use any email address in the FROM field while sending email through Gmail SMTP?

Tags: c#, gmail, smtpclient

I'm trying to send an email using gmail SMTP in C# using the code bellow

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.To.Add("my email");
message.Subject = "subject";
message.From = new MailAddress("any email");
message.Body = "body";

message.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(path));
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("my user", "my pass");

smtp.Send(message);
```

When I receive the email, the **FROM** field is filled with `my user`. I'm using `UseDefaultCredentials` as `false`. When I look to the result, the **FROM** field is filled with `my user`. Shouldn't the **FROM** field be filled with `any email`? How can I send an email using `any email` as sender?

Comment: I think this is a way for GMail to control use of its SMTP service. If anyone could send mail to anyone else via GMail, spammers would flock there. This way all emails sent 'on behalf of you' DO come from you (='my user')

Comment: I have already done this in a JAVA program... many years ago! :(

Comment: Did you have a chance to check full source of the email you are receiving? It should have "From: any email" and "Sender: my user instead". The app you are seeing the email with might be presenting Sender as if it was From, and causes the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having run your code snippet I get:

```
Return-Path: <my user>
Received: from Psi ([80.92.234.64])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id f1sm20531634wiy.2.2012.10.08.10.07.49
        (version=TLSv1/SSLv3 cipher=OTHER);
        Mon, 08 Oct 2012 10:07:49 -0700 (PDT)
Message-ID: <50730865.2152b40a.13ea.28ec@mx.google.com>
Sender: Roman R. <my user>
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: any email
To: my email
Date: Mon, 08 Oct 2012 10:07:49 -0700 (PDT)
Subject: Subject
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Body
```

`Sender` is the email address used to authenticate with Google Mail. `From` is the "from" provided in code. The receiving application might be confusing the two, and the rest looks just as expected. Some mail clients present the From+Sender (when they are different) as "sent by Sender on behalf of From".

You might be concerned with the fact that Google Mail still reveal the account from which the email is sent, through `Sender` field, but this is how it works. You do send from this account.

And, another possible reason is the `From` mail address itself. If you added it to your Google Mail account **as one of your own addresses** (and confirmed via test email with a link), then Google Mail will allow putting it onto `From` field. Otherwise it might drop it and replace it with the `Sender`.

Comment: I'm `gmail` settings there is a setting to change the `FROM` field. It's a better solution, it makes more professional. Is better receve an email from `support@my.company.com` than `support.my.company@gmail.com`

Comment: This was my point in last paragraph. If you added your email address as your own alternate address in GMail, you can put it onto `From` field in C# code as well. Otherwise it might be discarded, and on GMail you cannot put anything into "From", you choose only from the list of confirmed addresses too. As you can see from my quoted email in the answer, GMail correctly put From there, because "any mail" was one of my alternate addresses.

Answer (score 5):

I employ the very same to send email using GMail as a service. I originally set the `.From` property to "noreply@mydomain.com" but the email still arrives with the From header set to the account used to authenticate.

Faced with this problem, I used the `ReplyToList` property (`.ReplyToList.Add(MailAddress))`) so that recipients that reply to the message will be sending the reply to an email account other than the "automated" one that we use to send outgoing messages.

**Edit:**

For more information, see [this thread on Google Groups](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/gmail/o5hlYNQNxmk). Also, [a related answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8954767/161052).